# Node.js - I want to change my upload like module

Tags: javascript, node.js

**index.js**

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){ 
  res.cookie('filename', req.file.originalname, {signed:true});
  res.cookie('filesize', req.file.size, {signed:true});
  var filename = __dirname + '/../' + req.file.path;

   hash_module.hash(filename, function(hashResult) {
      res.cookie('hash', hashResult, {signed:true});
      res.redirect('/hash')
  })
})
```

**after**

```
var upload = (upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){
   res.cookie('filename', req.file.originalname, {signed:true});
   res.cookie('filesize', req.file.size, {signed:true});
   var filename = 'C:/nodejs/module/'+ req.file.path;

  hash_module.hash(filename, function(hashResult) { 
     res.cookie('hash', hashResult, {signed:true}); 
     res.redirect('/hash')
  })
 })
```

i want to change my code 'after', but it doesn't work.

i don't know how to do. I need your helps

Comment: You cannot put two argument values in one variable.

Comment: Can you show us how you intended to use that `upload` variable?

Comment: @Bergi route_info: [{file:'./index', path:'/upload', method:'upload', type:'post'} ] i want to use here like this.

Comment: @Lock what are you trying to do? It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you can't use the function like that.

```
 const multer = require('multer');
 var upload = multer({
     storage: storage
 }).single('userfile');

 router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
     upload(req, res, function(err) {
         if (err) {
             // This is a good practice when you want to handle your errors differently

             return
         }
         res.cookie('filename', req.file.originalname, {
             signed: true
         });
         res.cookie('filesize', req.file.size, {
             signed: true
         });
         var filename = __dirname + '/../' + req.file.path;

         hash_module.hash(filename, function(hashResult) {
             res.cookie('hash', hashResult, {
                 signed: true
             });
             res.redirect('/hash')
         })

     })
 })
```